# marzipano in Vue error - index.js window.bowser undefined

Tags: vue.js, webpack, window, undefined, marzipano

I'm having trouble with using Marzipano library in Vue.
I made Marzipano folder with marzipano tool and implanted in my Vue project.
But when the project is loaded, marzipano's 'index.js' file can't read below variables.

```
window.bowser
window.screenfull
window.APP_DATA
```

I get messages like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
> at webpack_require__

When I open the 'index.html' file from "Go Live" live server, it works perfectly. But get those error messages and get nothing when I run by vue-cli-service serve & webpack.
So I have a feeling I have to do something with webpack config setting.

Comment: Is `window.bowser` supposed to be `window.browser`? Could you post what you have on codesandbox.io so we can see the error?

Comment: It is bowser not browser.
what is codesandbox.io?
index.html calls varios scripts like

<script src="vendor/screenfull.min.js" ></script>
<script src="vendor/bowser.min.js" ></script>
<script src="vendor/marzipano.js" ></script>
<script src="data.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

I checked that all of above scripts were loaded 
but methods, variables in the scripts  weren't saved to window.bower, window.APP_data, window.screenfull... so 'index.js' file can't read them as undefined....

Comment: Read about [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/docs). You can use it to make your issue reproducible, so we could provide useful answers.